# invalid_grant error when attempting oAuth2 for Box API

Tags: http, oauth-2.0, box

I have been attempting to get access tokens for the Box API and am running into a persistent problem. I am following the steps listed on [this](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/docs/oauth-20) page. I am able to do the first leg and get a security token from a request to

`https://account.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&state=security_token%3DKnhMJatFipTAnM0nHlZA`

I am then doing a POST request to

`https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code={CODE_FROM_PREVIOUS_REQUEST}&client_id{MY_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={MY_CLIENT_SECRET}`

I also am including the header
`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

With all this I am getting back: 

`{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"
}`

Is there something I am missing here? Thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually POST-ing the parameters since you've included them in the URL as query parameters. You should pass the parameters as part of the HTTP request body.